# React: Having trouble with images on Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Web development, and I'm creating an eCommerce Website using react. I'm having trouble getting images to load onto the website from my backend server.

You can see a [Photo of HomeScreen.js file and the website itself here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aku5y.png)

It isnt pulling images from data.js in the backend folder. not sure why? Any help with this will be extremely appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Ronnie

Comment: Hey @ronnie-mize welcome!

Are you able to post a screenshot of the Product component as well? Not much we can interpret from the screenshot as of right now.

Comment: Welcome to SO, take a read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best support from members. Best not to post code screenshots.